# VBA Run-time error 1004 (possibly) caused by memory overflow

Tags: vba, loops, memory, runtime

I am struggling with a piece of VBA code. The idea is very simple: I would like to loop through a workbook of 10000 rows, copy each row and paste into a new workbook then save that new workbook. This is for the HR department. We are trying to copy and paste one row for each employee and send that piece of info over to that person.
This is what I have:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim EmployeeNumber As String
i = 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Activate
EmployeeNumber = Range("C1").Value
Do While EmployeeNumber <> ""
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
   NewBook.SaveAs "path& EmployeeNumber.xlsx"
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   EmployeeNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value
   i=i+1
 Set NewBook = Nothing
 Loop
```

This works for the first 500-700 rows, then it breaks(I tested it several times, each time the code broke at different rows). The error message was 
"Run-time error 1004, SaveAs method failed"

I highly suspect this was due to the high volume of data I was dealing with. Each time a row is copied and saved, a new VBAProject is created.

[image: See Picture]

Does anyone have the same issue before? Any help/input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a template workbook, then use SaveCopyAs to save each employee's info:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim NewBook As Workbook
    Dim rngEmployeeNum As Range

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Set rngEmployeeNum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1")

    Do While rngEmployeeNum.Value <> ""

       rngEmployeeNum.EntireRow.Copy NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

       NewBook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\employees\Emp_" & _
                          Format(rngEmployeeNum.Row, "0000") & ".xlsx"

       Set rngEmployeeNum = rngEmployeeNum.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    NewBook.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! I tried your suggestion and it solved my problem perfectly! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I give up I've had this running for a half hour without an issue.

Essentially, there is no difference in our code.  If this doesn't work try uncommenting `DoEvents`.  This my allow Excel time to clean up better.

[image]

```
Sub TestMakeFiles()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Const ROOT_FOLDER = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\stack-overflow\test\"
    Dim r As Range
    Dim NewBook As Workbook
    Dim EmployeeNumber As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        For Each r In Intersect(.Columns("C"), .UsedRange)
            With Workbooks.Add
                r.EntireRow.Copy Range("A1")
                .SaveAs ROOT_FOLDER & r.Value & ".xlsx"
                .Close
            End With
            'DoEvents
        Next
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer - Start
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could run your code several times with these modifications; until all the files are creates

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NewBook As Workbook
    Dim EmployeeNumber As String
    i = 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Activate
    EmployeeNumber = Range("C1").Value
    Do While EmployeeNumber <> ""
        If Dir(Len(Path & EmployeeNumber & ".xlsx")) = 0 Then
            Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
            NewBook.SaveAs Path & EmployeeNumber & ".xlsx"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            EmployeeNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```